# Cordova jquery ajax post to server php file

Tags: php, cordova

I want to compare input value of the input in the cordova app to an table in my database.

This is my jquery ajax post:

```
$('.postToken').click(function(){


  console.log($('.valueToken').val());
   var tokenValue = $('.valueToken').val();

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url:  "http://example.com/fysioWebapp/php/get_schema.php",
       data: { dataString: tokenValue },
       cache: false,
       success: function(){
          alert("Order Submitted");
          }
   });
```

and this is my get_schema.php on server:

```
 <?php
    include("connect.php");

    $stringData = $_POST['dataString'];
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    var_dump($stringData);
?>
```

But it returns me `null` I first type in value data in my cordova app and then refresh the php page but keeps returning me `null`. Could somebody help me out on this issue?

Comment: Did you use jquery mobile? You should use tap or touchstart event of jquery mobile. The click event will execute to fast in my experience which it get null on my Cordova app.

Comment: Not using jquery mobile, its just an basic setup for now. Want to use ionic2 in the future

Comment: Ok. Good luck for that. For some advises, you should use native way or xamarin to build an native app. The reason is that the webview's CSS calculation can be changed on different mobile and it is hard to maintain it. I had a ton of the worst experience on a webview app.( /^\ )

Comment: For Cordova, you should use jquery mobile for the clicking events which is the best way on your webview app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

You need to see if the value exists in the database table like this

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$stringData = $_POST['dataString'];
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$checkToken = "SELECT * FROM Exercises WHERE YOUR_FIELD_NAME = ('$stringData')";
$checkResult = mysqli_query($conn, $checkToken);

if (mysqli_num_rows($checkResult) > 0) {

echo "Result already exists";

} else {

echo "0 results";

}

?>
```

Replace YOUR_FIELD_NAME for the column name you use for tokens.

The javascript I have already provided will console log wether or not the token exists.

**Original**

When you refresh the php file $stringData will be undefined.

Try this.

```
$('.postToken').click(function(){
    console.log($('.valueToken').val());
    var tokenValue = $('.valueToken').val();

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url:  "http://example.com/fysioWebapp/php/get_schema.php",
       data: { dataString: tokenValue },
       cache: false,
       success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
           alert("Order Submitted");
       }
    });
});
```

This should console log the result of the var_dump.

If not change this line of the php file.

```
var_dump($stringData);
```

To.

```
echo var_dump($stringData);
```

Comment: And than how can I compare datastring in php if it isnundefined?

Comment: What would you like to compare it with? Something from you data base?

Comment: This is my console.log: `string(4) "test" string(4) "test" 0 results`. And this is my var_dump on php: `NULL NULL 0 results`

Comment: I want to check if that stringdata is the same as in table Exercises than it has to show content belonging to Token in Exercises.

Comment: Can I ask why you are calling var_dump? The console log proves that var_dump is working correctly. So the 0 results in console log means that no token was found in the table that matches your input. Try putting a token in the table and then putting the same token into you app and see what the console logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141818/discussion-between-sreinieren-and-l-balsdon).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just use ajax in your cordova app because of cross domain issues. Either you have to setup your server or php to get it or you can use `jsonp`.

For ajax solution you can try this on your php:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]);
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, referer, content-type");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000");

    if(strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'OPTIONS'){
        header("Content-Type: text/plain");
        header("Content-Length: 0");
        http_response_code(204);
        exit;
    }

include("connect.php");

$stringData = $_POST['dataString'];
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

var_dump($stringData);
?>
```

Comment: tried and pasted your code in my get_schema.php but not working.